# ref undefined in React Native

Tags: react-native

Can someone help me in figuring out wha is the best way to use setNativeProps in RN?.

In my react function component I did something like this

```
const AutoComplete = (props) => {
 let parentViewRef = null

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(function(){ console.log(parentViewRef) }, 3000)
  },[])

  return(
    <View  
      ref={(viewRef) => { 
        parentViewRef = viewRef 
      }}
      style={styles.modelOpenViewMain}>    <View style={styles.modelOpenInputView}>

           </View>
        </View>
    )
  }
}
```

But unfortunately my parentViewRef is coming out to be undefined. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly what you're trying to achieve, then you should be using [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook.

So your code would look like something like this:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

const AutoComplete = (props) => {
 let parentViewRef = useRef(null);

  return(
    <View  
      ref={parentViewRef}
      style={styles.modelOpenViewMain}>    <View style={styles.modelOpenInputView}>

           </View>
        </View>
    )
  }
}
```

You will then be able to do whatever you want with your ref via its `current` property, e.g. 
`parentViewRef.current.` ...

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try Passing the parentViewRef as an argument to the useEffect method.

```
    const AutoComplete = (props) => {
    
    let parentViewRef = null

    useEffect(() => { 

           console.log(parentViewRef);

    }, [parentViewRef]);

    return (
        <View
            ref={(viewRef) => parentViewRef = viewRef}>
            <View >
                <Text>CONTENT TEXT</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
      )
    }
```